# how to exit from a recv call

Tags: c, sockets

I'm reading from one socket, but I don't know how many elements will arrive, so my socket remains stuck on the recv call also if the server has written all the elements of the struct array.

Client

```
for(;;){
     ...
     if(strcmp(buf,"!who")==0){
        while(recv(sd,name,50,0)>0)
        {

            printf("%s\n",name);

        }
        continue;
    }
}
```

Server

```
while(recv(sock,msg,1024,0)>0){

    if(strcmp(msg,"!who")==0){
        if(i==0){
                strcpy(msg2,"Nessun giocatore collegato.");
                write(sock,msg2,strlen(msg2));
        }
        else
            for(int c=0;c<=i;c++)
                write(sock,players[c].name,strlen(players[c].name));

    }

}
```

Comment: Have your server first send a (fixed-length) indication of how many bytes it is planning to send next.  You client can first read that indicator (since the indicator is fixed-length the client knows how many bytes to recv() to read it), and then once it has that information, your client will know how many more bytes to read in order to receive all the elements of the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't know how many elements will arrive

You have to know.  You have 3 options:

1. Sender prefixes the data with a count, telling the receiver how much to expect.
2. Sender concludes the data with some kind of "done" marker.  In your case, a `0` would do (indicating a zero-length name).
3. Sender closes the connection, and receiver sees `EOF`.

I would change the protocol to send `strlen` first, then the name.

Note also that TCP has no message boundaries.  **recv**(2) returns *N* bytes, where *N* is whatever was convenient for the kernel.  If the call was interrupted by a signal, or the internal buffers were unable to accommodate the sender's output, *N* will be less than what was sent, and the next `recv` will get more of it (perhaps all of it).

As written, your code retrieves a name, followed by its length.  But there is no assurance that the last bytes received constitute the length; if more data are pending, they will just be part of the name.